# How to remove the borders around the powerline on spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, border, customization, spacemacs, powerline

I just installed Spacemacs using https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport When I open it on my Retina Macbook Pro I see a "border" on the powerline and the color isn't even (notice under utf-8 on the right that it's thicker).

How do I remove either the darker/thicker border or remove the powerline border?

I was unable to find this is the readme for powerline for emacs.

[image: spacemacs powerline with border]

Answer (score 0):

Likely the problems you're seeing are coming from using a weird version of Emacs with Spacemacs.

The repo you linked to says

> Note that Emacs 23 and later already contain the official GUI support
>   via the NS (Cocoa) port for Mac OS X 10.4 and later. So if it is good
>   enough for you, then you don't need to try this.

So it sounds like that repo is made obsolete by vanilla Emacs 23+, which I've always downloaded from https://emacsformacosx.com/. With the latest version of Emacs, hopefully your problems will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. This is the verison suggested by spacemacs in the readme, but I did try it and they look the same. I noticed that other themes don't have this, so I have just discarded solarized and started working on using similar colors or another theme with spacemacs. You suggested app is easier to install and has a nicer Icon